# Modify Quality Profiles with Project Permissions

Tags: sonarqube

I am looking for a option so that the member (or a subset of them) can modify the quality profiles which there use for the project. Till this point I only found out that I can give the user the permissions to modify all profiles but not only the profile which is assign to the project.
I don't know if my explanation what i am looking for is good enough but my goal is to provide sonarqube for multiple teams so every team can only modify there own configuration.
best regards
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the most wanted features on SonarQube, please vote for it on [SONAR-1330](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-1330).